# Increasing an elements width and height momentarily while retaining its centred position with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, height, width

I am trying to increase a div's width and height such that at certain amount of time the inner circle should fill up outer circle by increasing its size. I am able to do everything but just the position is causing a bit of problem. As the dimensions of the inner circle increasing its losing its centre position and increasing towards bottom right. How can I keep increasing its width and height but keep it in the center such that when it is completed it fills up the outer circle completely. Many thanks

```js
var outer, inner, width, interval, height;
inner = document.querySelector(".inner");
width = 0;
height = 0;

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (width >= 200 && height >= 200) {
            inner.textContent = "100% Completed";
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        else {

            width += 3.333;
            height += 3.333;
            inner.style.width = width + "px";
            inner.style.height = height + "px";
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add a `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to the `inner` circle class. This ensures that it is centred properly.

```js
var outer, inner, width, interval, height;
inner = document.querySelector(".inner");
width = 0;
height = 0;

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
 
  interval = setInterval(function(){
  
if ( width >= 200 && height >= 200 ) {
  inner.textContent = "100% Completed";
  clearInterval(interval);
}

else {

    width += 3.333;
    height += 3.333;
    inner.style.width = width + "px";
    inner.style.height = height + "px";

}
    
    },500);
  
});
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response and a great answer, thumbs up D-Money